# How do I unblur an image on hover with css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: Thank you to all who answered! The solutions worked and it is great. The reason I used javascript is because the person I originally asked for help from told me to use it and we both forgot that hover existed in css. Again, thank you!

I am making a website for a school project and want to blur/censor an image and have it unblur/uncensor the image when hovered over but I'm running into issues with making that happen.

Here is my code:

```
uncensor.onmouseover = function(x){
    censor.style.filter = "none"
}
censor.onmouseover = function(x){
    censor.style.filter = "blur(5px)"
}

 <img onmousehover="uncensor(this)" onmouseout="censor(this)" src="https://s.abcnews.com/images/International/beirut-explosion-13-ap-rc-200805_hpMain_16x9_1600.jpg" id="img-blur">
 <img onmousehover="uncensor(this)" onmouseout="censor(this)" src="https://media.nature.com/lw800/magazine-assets/d41586-020-02361-x/d41586-020-02361-x_18261790.jpg" id="img-blur">

#img-blur{
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your issues? Are any errors thrown (in your console), etc.? Could you add some more Informations?

Comment: Why are you not using just CSS?

Comment: FYI there is no `onmousehover` event

Answer (score 1):

You can do that **without javascript**. Just use the `hover` selector:

```css
img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

img:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/250px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pure CSS:

```css
.img-blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.img-blur:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s.abcnews.com/images/International/beirut-explosion-13-ap-rc-200805_hpMain_16x9_1600.jpg" class="img-blur">
<img src="https://media.nature.com/lw800/magazine-assets/d41586-020-02361-x/d41586-020-02361-x_18261790.jpg" class="img-blur">
```

But if javascript is a must, here is a workaround: your `censor` and `uncensor` functions are receiving the element hovered on/out of, so you need to change the style for `x` itself (the argument). Also make sure you are not using the same id more than once - this would lead to unexpected behaviour.

```js
const uncensor = function(x) {
  x.style.filter = "none"
}
const censor = function(x) {
  x.style.filter = "blur(5px)"
}
```

```css
.img-blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="uncensor(this)" onmouseout="censor(this)" src="https://s.abcnews.com/images/International/beirut-explosion-13-ap-rc-200805_hpMain_16x9_1600.jpg" class="img-blur">
<img onmouseover="uncensor(this)" onmouseout="censor(this)" src="https://media.nature.com/lw800/magazine-assets/d41586-020-02361-x/d41586-020-02361-x_18261790.jpg" class="img-blur">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use JavaScript to add and remove the blur. You can do it just with CSS with `:hover`

```css
.img-blur{
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.img-blur:hover {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<img class="img-blur" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />


<img class="img-blur" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
```

If you want to do this with JavaScript add mouseenter and mouseleave to the images.

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img-blur");

imgs.forEach(function (img) {
  img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    img.style.filter = 'blur(0px)';
  });
  img.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    img.style.filter = 'blur(5px)';  
  });
});
```

```css
.img-blur{
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<img class="img-blur" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
<img class="img-blur" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `:hover` in the css? btw the way consider that you must not put same id for some elements in the page.

```css
.img-blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.img-blur:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/550000/?text=Image1" class="img-blur">
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000000/?text=Image1" class="img-blur">
```

Comment: He want to have it blurred and only unblurred on hover. :) The other way around.

Comment: right, I edited my response, Thank you.